# Remove a fragment with linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a linear layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:text="Default Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30dip" />
```

and in my activity (container of two fragments), I call:

```
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FragmentContainer)).commit();
```

where FragmentConteiner is an id that I used with a FrameLayout (insted LinearLayout) but I got a `NullPointerException`

WHich is the correct id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove fragments using Fragment Manager using TAGs assigned to fragments. So you code would be:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TAG).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to replace fragment, how can use tag??

Comment: Use the same TAG name and then use replace for that particular fragment. And you create Fragment once for most of the cases, and not multiple time, and if you need to there are other many threads that help you.

Comment: now I have: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="unique_tag" >

Comment: and in my activity: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("unique_tag").commit();

Comment: Is the tag assigned to a fragment at the time of creation of fragment?

Comment: I recommend you put it programatically. It would be much simpler, and its the container i.e, `FrameLayout` meaning any fragment can be loaded onto this container. If you have 10 Fragments all these can be loaded on a single container, addition/removal can be handled using TAG names to the fragments.

Comment: yes, but I should "design" the fragment as linearlayout or framelayout? (in the xml layout of fragment)

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` as parent and `FrameLayout` as child

Comment: and the android:tag where should I put it?

Comment: You could use something like this:
`if(mFragManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAG)!= null)
   showFragmentFoo(mFragManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAG), TAG_FRAG);
  else 
   showFragmentFoo(new customFragment(),TAG_FRAG);`

Comment: but the "tag" in the xml where do I put it? In the framelayout or relative/linear layout?